# What is the different between adding slash and without it in front of an ajax URL

Tags: php, ajax

I have this code here

```
$(document).on('change', '.item_category', function(){
        var category_id = $(this).val();
        var sub_category_id = $(this).data('sub_category_id');
        $.ajax({
          url:"fill_sub_category.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{category_id:category_id},
          success:function(data)
          {
            var html = '<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>';
            html += data;
            $('#item_sub_category'+sub_category_id).html(html);
          }
        })
      });
```

when I added a slash in front of fill_sub_category.php. It will not call the file and if I moved this file to a subfolder. I will get the same issue.

> url:"/fill_sub_category.php",

My question is, why adding a slash causes this problem, and is it possible to move this file to a subfolder, if so what is the proper way of writing it.  I have tried url:"includes/fill_sub_category.php", but it didn't make any changes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see it we need to consider the folder with the .js file (where .js file contains the AJAX code).

if php code is in the same folder, we can use

```
url:"./fill_sub_category.php"   //or
url:"fill_sub_category.php"
```

if (with absolute dir reference) php code is in server root directory, we can use

```
url:"/fill_sub_category.php"
```

or (with relative dir reference) if e.g. .js is in c:/somefolder1/js
while .php is in  c:/somefolder1/php, we can use

```
url:"../php/fill_sub_category.php"
```

where ../ means we want to move up to parent directory . ' hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Ruperto, that explains a lot. cheer